# What open source home automation software exists? What are the differences between them?

Tags: home-automation, software

I just bought my first apartment and I am now looking to setup a cheap home automation system.

I would like to control :

- light
- electric shutter
- heater thermostat
- other stuff in the future

I am looking to an open source software that I could install into a cheap linux box and which could be accessible from internet (mobile or desktop) with a nice UI.
It would be best if it was technology independant (not X10 only for example) and plugin base to be able to add support for a new specific device in the futur.

I am also ready to do some code hacking to make it better as I am a web developer. I am a software and electronics engineer so not afraid of new tech.

A good community supporting the software is also a plus.

---

For info this is what I found with a first internet search :

- http://www.domogik.org/
- http://www.openami.de/
- http://misterhouse.sourceforge.net/
- http://lifedomus.blogspot.com/
- http://www.opensourceautomation.com/
- http://www.linuxha.com/linuxha/
- http://www.catrpillr.com/

Comment: This is something very interesting. What kind of hardware is required to interface with this?

Comment: Have you heard of the [Nest](http://www.nest.com/)? It really goes above and beyond in automation features for a thermostat, but all the while still being more simple and intuitive to manage than any other thermostat.

Comment: It seems like support for the home automation protocol (INSTEON vs. x10 vs. Zigbee, two or more supported technologies, etc) would be very important to know.

Comment: I've protected this since this sort of question tends to attract spam answers. For those that answer this question with a product link, realize that there's a high likelihood in the community flagging your answer as spam.

Answer (score 3):

So far all the arduino/home automations I have seen are custom built. We are planning on using **[Domotic Home](http://www.domotichome.net/welcomes)** in our hacker group.

Answer (score 3):

Collecting the previous suggestions, I believe this is a good place to start a wiki discussion, since it's not a direct Q/A:

- http://www.domogik.org/
- http://www.openami.de/
- http://misterhouse.sourceforge.net/
- http://lifedomus.blogspot.com/
- http://www.opensourceautomation.com/
- http://www.linuxha.com/linuxha/
- http://www.catrpillr.com/
- http://freedomotic.com/
- http://majordomohome.com/
- http://www.nest.com/
- http://www.domotichome.net/
- http://en.opendomo.org/
- http://www.jubito.org/
- https://ifttt.com/

Maybe the community can enrich this list with experiences, oppinions, etc. I found it appropriate for this specific topic. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Another open-source project: http://majordomohome.com/

Answer (score 1):

Look up a video demo for the LinuxMCE project.  (Be sure to watch the video, it's hard to really "get it" until you've seen it in action.)

Pretty impressive IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [FreeDomotic](http://freedomotic.com/)? You may be impressed by the flexibility and the polyvalence of the protocol and the core engine.

Comment: Please explain why you are suggesting this as answer in terms a DIYer would understand. At the moment this reads like spam.

Comment: What does _polyvalence_ mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Another open source solution for you might be [www.jubito.org](http://www.jubito.org).

Answer (score 0):

I saw a interesting project. [curuba](http://www.curuba.org) is Open Source and Open Hardware. It uses WiFi network.

Also, you can use it in any platform. (Android, Apple, BlackBerry, etc.).